# The Jacobson radical of polynomial ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $R[x]$ be the polynomial ring over $R$. We know that the Jacobson radical $J(R[x] )$ of  $R[x]$ is the intersection of all maximal ideals of $R[x]$. Now let $M$ be a fixed (but arbitrary) maximal ideal of $R[x]$. How can we show that $J(R[x])=\cap_{M\not=N\in \mathrm{Max}(R[x])}N$, where $\mathrm{Max}(R[x])$ is the set of all maximal ideals of $R[x]$?

Comment: just to clarify, is this saying that in the ring $R[x]$ you can take the set of maximal ideals, kick one of them out, intersect the remaining ones, and still get the Jacobson radical as the result of the intersection?

Comment: @Prince M, exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to show is the following:

> $f\not \in M \implies f\not \in N $ for some maximal ideal $N\neq M$. $(*)$

Let $M'=R\cap M$, $R'=R／M'$ and $f'=[f]\in R'$. Then any maximal ideal in $R'[x]$ not containing $f'$ correspond to a maximal ideal in $R[x]$ not containing $f$. So if we can prove $(*)$ for the ring $R'$, then $(*)$ is also true for $R$. Hence we may assume $R$ is an integral domain, and $R\cap M=0$.

Note that we already have a contradiction if $R$ is a field, this follows from that $R[x]$ has infinitely many prime elements, and only a finite number of them can divide $f$. So we may assume $R$ is not a field, in particular, we assume $R$ is infinite.

Let $K=R[x]/M$, regard $R$ as a subring of $K$. Suppose $M$ is the kernel of the surjective map $R[x]\to K$ sending $x$ to $\alpha \in K$. For any $r\in R$, let $M_r$ be kernel of the surjective map $R[x] \to K$ sending $x$ to $\alpha+r$
(and fix $R$). Since $R$ is infinite, we may can $r$ so that $\alpha+r$ is not a conjugate of $\alpha$, and $f(\alpha+r)\neq 0$. Then $M_r\neq M$ is another maximal ideal not containing $f$.

Comment: Why is it that the two maximal ideals in $R[x]_f$ correspond to maximal ideals in $R[x]$? I see that they would be at least bijectively correspond to two prime ideals not containing $f$, but how to see they are maximal? And can you elaborate on the reduction to $R$ a domain?

Comment: Yes, you are right. A maximal ideal in $R[x]_f$ may not correspond to a maximal ideal in $R[x]$. But a maximal ideal in $R[x]$ not containing $f$ should correspond to a maximal ideal in $R[x]_f$, and this is the implication we need, right?

Comment: I believe you are correct, I just want to make sure I understand why (*) implies the first highlighted line of your answer. So once we have two distinct maximal ideals in $R[x]_f$, say $\mathfrak{m}_1$, $\mathfrak{m_2}$, how to use this to show $f \notin M \implies f \notin N$, for some maximal $N$?

Comment: Please elaborate on how the maximal ideal not containing f’ corresponds to a maximal ideal not containing f, I do not see how you are applying the correspondence theorem. Also, why does that mean we can reduce to the case when R is an integral domain? In your final paragraph, in what way are we regarding R as a sub ring of a quotient of R? Also in your final paragraph it appears M is an ideal of R yet then how is M the kernel of the evaluation? No element of R would be in the Kernal

Comment: If $M'$ is a maximal ideal not containing $f'$,  then its preimage in $R[x]$ is a maximal ideal not containing $f$.

Comment: Preimage under what map? R’[x] is not a quotient of R[x]?

Comment: And it is clear that $M$ is the kernel of the natural map $R[x] \to R[x]/M$? I just denote the image of $x$ by $\alpha$. Also, since $R\ cap M=0$, the composition $R \to R[x] \to K$ is injective, so we can regard $R$ as a subring of $K$ via this map.

Comment: There is a natural map $R[x]\to R'[x]$ induced from the map $R\to R'$. Or you can think that $R'[x]=R[x]/M'[x]$

Comment: Something must be wrong in your definition of K

Comment: Oh yes, $K$ should be $R[x]/M$.Thanks

Comment: Would it follow from this that R[x] cannot be local?

Comment: Yes, but in fact if $m$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, then $m[x]$ and $m[x+1]$ are two maximal ideals of $R[x]=R[x+1]$

Comment: For $m \in \text{max}(R),$ $m[x]$ is not maximum ideal of $R[x].$ But $<m,x>$ is maximal ideal of $R[x].$